# Hot to transform multiple dataframes to specific format?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
      "database": {
        "0": "database1",
        "1": "database1",
        "2": "database1",
      },
      "table": {
        "0": "table A",
        "1": "table B",
        "2": "table C",
      },
      "node": {
        "0": "node1",
        "1": "node1",
        "2": "node1",
      },
      "value": {
        "0": "A1",
        "1": "B1",
        "2": "C1",
      }
    })


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
      "database": {
        "0": "database1",
        "1": "database1",
        "2": "database1",
      },
      "table": {
        "0": "table B",
        "1": "table C",
        "2": "table D",
      },
      "node": {
        "0": "node2",
        "1": "node2",
        "2": "node2",
      },
      "value": {
        "0": "B2",
        "1": "C2",
        "2": "D2",
      }
    })
df2

df1
    database    table   node    value
0   database1   table A node1   A1
1   database1   table B node1   B1
2   database1   table C node1   C1

df2
    database    table   node    value
0   database1   table B node2   B2
1   database1   table C node2   C2
2   database1   table D node2   D2
```

How to transform these two dataframes to this format?

[image]

Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to submit the question due: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.".
I added this text just to pass further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for join DataFrame together and then use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with aggregate function `first` for return first values by triples `table,database,node`:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
       .pivot_table(index='table', 
                    columns=['database','node'], 
                    values='value', 
                    aggfunc='first'))
print (df)

database database1      
node         node1 node2
table                   
table A         A1   NaN
table B         B1    B2
table C         C1    C2
table D        NaN    D2
```

If possible duplicates by triples `table,database,node` then use aggregation by `join` for avoid lost data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
      "database": {
        "0": "database1",
        "1": "database1",
        "2": "database1",
      },
      "table": {
        "0": "table A",
        "1": "table A", 
        "2": "table C",
      },
      "node": {
        "0": "node1",
        "1": "node1",
        "2": "node1",
      },
      "value": {
        "0": "A1",
        "1": "B1",
        "2": "C1",
      }
    })
```

---

```
print (df1)
    database    table   node value
0  database1  table A  node1    A1  <- duplicated triple
1  database1  table A  node1    B1  <- duplicated triple
2  database1  table C  node1    C1
```

---

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
       .pivot_table(index='table', 
                    columns=['database','node'], 
                    values='value', 
                    aggfunc=','.join))
print (df)
database database1      
node         node1 node2
table                   
table A      A1,B1   NaN
table B        NaN    B2
table C         C1    C2
table D        NaN    D2
```

If use `first` with duplicated triples, only first value is returned:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
       .pivot_table(index='table', 
                    columns=['database','node'], 
                    values='value', 
                    aggfunc='first'))
print (df)
database database1      
node         node1 node2
table                   
table A         A1   NaN  <- B1 is lost
table B        NaN    B2
table C         C1    C2
table D        NaN    D2
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I really liked aggfunc=','.join.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the dataframes and pivot:

```
(pd.concat((df1,df2))
   .pivot_table(columns='node', 
                   index=['database','table'], 
                   values='value',
                   aggfunc='first')
   .unstack('database')
   .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
database     database1      
node         node1 node2
table                   
table A         A1   NaN
table B         B1    B2
table C         C1    C2
table D        NaN    D2
```